# Trying to set Child for firebase database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I am trying to add a chat message to the database and I am using the child constructor to put a timestamp with the message so it doesn't keep overwriting itself but for some reason it doesn't add the childs, it just overrights  Here's my code:

```
private fun sendData(){

        val editText = groupsInput
        val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        val myRef = database.getReference("message")

        myRef.setValue(com.ntx_deisgns.cyberchatter.cyberchatter.Message(editText.text.toString()))
        val mDatabase: DatabaseReference? = null
        mDatabase?.
                child("Group Chat")?.
                child(java.lang.String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()))?.
                setValue(com.ntx_deisgns.cyberchatter.cyberchatter.Message(editText.text.toString()))

        //clear the text
        editText.setText("")
    }
```

Notice that I set a child of "group chat" and a child of `java.lang.String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())` but for some reason, it does not add those children at all.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why the message is being saved twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide a value for mDatabase.  It is currently null and therefore cannot be used to send your data to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a push,

```
child("Group Chat").push().child(java.lang.String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())).setValue(com.ntx_deisgns.cyberchatter.cyberchatter.Message(editText.text.toString()))
```

Right now you have it set so it only is getting the Group Chat child and then just changing the data everytime but not creating a new child with a new timestamp. So the push would generate a random key and then insert the timestamp.